# Jumping setup on a sidescroller javascript

Tags: javascript

i`m trying to make this object jump, but i have no idea how to make a good jump,
when you hold the up arrow key the object just goes up, can someone suggest any ideas ?

```
http://jsfiddle.net/qLw4sgLr/3/
```

main problem is here :

```
if (keys[38]) {
        velY -= 2;    // this is the up arrow key 
    }

    velY++; // this acts like gravity

    if (keys[39]) {
        if (velX < speed) {
            velX++;
        }
    }  ///// left and right movement
    if (keys[37]) {
        if (velX > -speed) {
            velX--;
        }
    }
```

i tried to release the up key when it is pressed, but it didn't work, 
i have also tried setting an invisible line above the object but that didn't work as well

Comment: Can you please include a fiddle for this, I can't imagine most people out there could visualise the action of this script easily just from the code :)

Comment: yes,
http://jsfiddle.net/qLw4sgLr/2/ this is the jsfiddle
and im using an image for the object that i want to move
this is the image i have no idea how to import it in js fidle 
http://i61.tinypic.com/347jxgi.png

Comment: Try this fiddle instead and copy it into your question, I have tidied it up for you: http://jsfiddle.net/qLw4sgLr/3/